# Problem with capital 'S' on Chrome.

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

As you can see, there seems to be some problem with the capital letter 'S' on Chrome 10.0.648.82 beta. (It seems to have a problem with the number '0' as well.)

[image]

**Edit:** I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Comment: You forgot to mention your operating system and what fonts you have installed. I suspect this is a bug in your font or rendering engine — is it really specific to this site? What about other browsers?

Comment: @Gilles: Silly me! I guess I left out some important things.

Comment: Why is this on meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in Chrome / Windows 7. As Gilles noted, this is probably an OS or browser specific problem of some kind with fonts.

Comment: Probably, because I can't even reproduce it myself today :) Thanks anyway.